# Show a menu Item based on specific User role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate

I need help showing a specific menu item if user role is "Affiliate".
Menu Item is "Affiliate Dashboard"
Don't want to use any plugin for such task.
Site is under maintenance mode so I can't show the site, However I've attached screenshot.
Please take a look and help me out.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will hide "Affiliate Dashboard" menu item if the current user role is not "affiliate":

The code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'show_hide_affiliate_menu_item', 500 );
function show_hide_affiliate_menu_item() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'yith_affiliate' ) )
        echo '<style> .top-bar-nav #menu-item-11874 { display: none !important } </style>'; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', 500 );' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/.../wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php on line 130

Comment: @AliKhan Sorry there was a missing `'` character… Try it again it should work this time.

Comment: I tired but it didn't worked. However changing the css to .top-bar-nav #menu-item-11874 {display: none} worked but it disabled the menu item for every user.

Comment: @AliKhan Updated my code again with your CSS rule… In my code you need to be sure that `affiliate` is the right user role. if not it doesn't work.

Comment: It's working. Role ID was " yith_affiliate " not just affiliate.

Comment: @AliKhan I just took what you give us on your question… I don't use affiliate plugin, so I can't guess that. My code allow to set any user role. Now please if you like/want you could please upvote this answer too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a if condition for do this..Example

```
if(Auth::user()->has('Affiliate')) {
   <a href="/affiliate-dashboard">Affiliate Dashboard</a>

}
```

But it's only possible when your user have assigned specific role